# Using Guava for checking generics class

Tags: java, generics, reflection, guava

I know that what I present here is bad but still - I need to do this ...
I would like to check class of generic in given method. I tried using Guava and description from here: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ReflectionExplained#Introduction
This is something that I have and I don't fully understand why it doesn't work:
```

```
abstract static public class IKnowMyType<T> {
    public TypeToken<T> type = new TypeToken<T>(getClass()) {};
}

protected <P> void abc(P el){
    System.out.println(new IKnowMyType<P>(){}.type);
}

protected <P> void abc(){
    System.out.println(new IKnowMyType<P>(){}.type);
}

void test(){
    System.out.println(new IKnowMyType<String>(){}.type); // -> java.lang.String
    this.abc("AA"); // -> P
    this.<String>abc(); // -> P
}
```

What I would like to get is proper class of `P` (String in this case) rather than `P`. How to do this? Why those `abc` methods doesn't work as I expect?

Comment: Generic-specified types are erased at runtime, so you *cannot* access such information.  However, the name of the generic placeholder, in this case `P`, is retained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to do what you're trying to do, and this is working exactly as expected.

Type erasure destroys generic type information of objects at runtime, as well as knowledge of the type arguments of methods (like you're finding out here).  What type erasure doesn't affect is that classes know their compile-time generic types, so e.g. if you have

```
class Foo<T> {}

class Bar extends Foo<String>
```

then `Bar.class` knows that it is a subclass of `Foo<String>`, not just `Foo`.  That's how `TypeToken` works, but it only works when the type is fixed at compile-time; it can't be left as a type variable.